# Entity Framework migration issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity framework and code first approach in my project. I have done some  Migrations to my server database and it was working fine. now I added a few more tables and try to create a migration by `add-migration` command to the database on server.

The command runs with no error and created a migration file.

But, when I check the migration file the code in the migration file was to create all tables again to database (`create table` for already created tables are also in the up method).

When I run `Update-database` command it returned an error saying

> ...table already exist in database.

I try it on some local database on my system and it was working fine.

Can anyone help me with this?

Is there any special permission to set in the server?

Is it because some services from visual studio getting blocked? If so how can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like you ran `add-migration` against the wrong database name, and it created you a new one as if it was an initial migration. Just delete the migration and run it again.

Comment: Are you sure that you run add migration and update database for the same database? And check if __efmigrationhistory table has proper records.

Comment: Check the __MigrationHistory table. There should be records for the prior migrations. If add-migration is trying to recreate existing files, then it means you have some issue with the prior migrations like a changed context key. If there are no prior migrations, then that is your problem.

Comment: The database is same and `__MigrationHistory` table have previous data .only the migration file creation has the issue. When i created a migration file and edit it properly the `update -database` works. I suspect there is some service which compare both `database` and `entity` to find the difference and some how it is getting blocked. But I have no idea about such a process. please help.

Comment: The compare happens when you do `add-migration`. It looks at the model embedded in the prior migration code file and scripts out the differences. If the migration `Up()` code has existing objects from prior migrations, then that is where the process is breaking. When you `update-database` it looks to see what migrations have been applied by checking __MigrationHistory. So if the issue is an old migration is trying to be re-applied this is where the problem lies (context key changed, records missing from table,  etc).

Comment: You can also try to create just the SQL Script for a specific version change / migration using the following command: `Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: FromMigration -TargetMigration: ToMigration` (replacing FromMigration and ToMigration accordingly). This can help circumvent problems like these, where EF is seemingly unable to determine the current DB state.